# Logstash add associated data into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have 3 different datasources which I want to combine into one elasticsearch index.

```
DS1 Author: { id: number, name: string ...}
DS2 Genre: {id: number, name:string ...}
DS3 Book: {id: number, name: string, author_id: number, genre_id: number ...}
```

So while storing book in elasticsearch (output), I want to mutate the data and add associated genre and author. The approaches I have thought of so far are:

1. Since author and genre are already in ES, use elasticsearch filter for each book, get associated author and genre and mutate the data.
2. Use `%[book_id]-%[author_id]-%[genre_id]` as the document index and upsert author and genre data with pattern: `*-%[author_id]-*` and `*-%[genre_id]` patterns. I am not sure if this is even possible.

What is the best approach to be taken in this situation? The number of books are not so much (~8000 records).